# morris.js on rails 3.2.1 cannot get json from html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, morris.js

I have a strange error on the morris.js graphing library

this works
in graphs.js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  Morris.Line({
  element: 'annual',
    data: [
    {y: '2012', a: 100},
    {y: '2011', a: 75},
    {y: '2010', a: 50},
    {y: '2009', a: 75},
    {y: '2008', a: 50},
    {y: '2007', a: 75},
    {y: '2006', a: 100}
  ],
    xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Series A']
});
})
```

this does not
graphs.js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  Morris.Line({
  element: 'annual',
    data: $('#logs_chart').data('logs'),
    xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Series A']
});
})
```

in the corresponding html

```
<div data-logs="[
    {y: '2012', a: 100},
    {y: '2011', a: 75},
    {y: '2010', a: 50},
    {y: '2009', a: 75},
    {y: '2008', a: 50},
    {y: '2007', a: 75},
    {y: '2006', a: 100}
  ]" id="logs_chart"></div>
```

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined  morris.js:316

Morris.parseDate = function(date) {
    var isecs, m, msecs, n, o, offsetmins, p, q, r, ret, secs;
    if (typeof date === 'number') {
      return date;
    }
    m = date.match(/^(\d+) Q(\d)$/);
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
    n = date.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)$/);
```

Has someone encountered this and found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the solution was to put the json output in a variable in a script tag at the end of the HTML.

Like this

```
<script> 

 var json_data = [
    {y: '2012', a: 100},
    {y: '2011', a: 75},
    {y: '2010', a: 50},
    {y: '2009', a: 75},
    {y: '2008', a: 50},
    {y: '2007', a: 75},
    {y: '2006', a: 100}
  ]

</script>
```

and call this variable in the graphs.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  Morris.Line({
  element: 'annual',
    data: json_data,
    xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Series A']
});
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Stuffing the graph data in data-logs isn't working because it's a string. You'll need to parse the data using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) or similar.

It's also worth noting that the data you've got in your example isn't strictly valid JSON, you need to escape the keys, eg:

```
<div data-logs='[
    {"y": "2012", "a": 100},
    {"y": "2011", "a": 75},
    {"y": "2010", "a": 50},
    {"y": "2009", "a": 75},
    {"y": "2008", "a": 50},
    {"y": "2007", "a": 75},
    {"y": "2006", "a": 100}
  ]' id="logs_chart"></div>
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  Morris.Line({
    element: 'annual',
    data: $.parseJSON($('#logs_chart').data('logs')),
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['Series A']
  });
})
```